# NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 Output Window

Tags: java, debugging, error-handling, netbeans-8, software-design

How can I open output window in NetBeans IDE 8.0.2? I tried multiple options below:

1. Go to Window option> Click on output
2. Clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>
3. Right click on the bottom right corner of NetBeans and Click on Show Output

Unfortunately, none of the options are working out. I see NetBeans is “running process” when clicked on Run but output does not show. And when clicked on stop process, the system gets hanged.

Please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try Window>Reset Windows to revert to your originial netbeans UI config.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your window in the question?

Comment: It’s strange because now when I clicked on Tools>Output, I see the output window is back again. The same option wasn’t working before. So, basically, I had to click on window>windows reset>tools>output to get output window back again. 
Thank you for your help Joey. I was going crazy from past 4 hours to make it work. Your efforts helped!

Comment: @BinalPatel Please accept my answer if you are satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Well sometimes even if you try Window->Output(Ctrl+4) option, it seems not to be working because your Editor window is maximized. Drag your mouse to the top right corner of the editor, where the restore/maximize button located. Click on the restore. Hope it will solve the issue.